# How to find the cause of blocking finalizer in .NET?

Tags: .net, blocking, finalizer

In Java I need only to press a single key (ctrl-break) to see the stacktrace of a blocking finalizer.

Is there a simple solution to see this also in .NET which can understand a Java programmer?

Comment: If you are debugging in visual studio, you can pause the execution and view the stack trace of any running thread. VS 2015 has additional diagnostics, and there is a concurrency visualizer plugin available for other VS versions that may show you what it is you are looking for (if it even matters in a .net context).

Answer (score 1):

may be you should pause `ctrl+alt+break` and look into a threads window `ctrl+d, t` for search blocking

Comment: Where should I press this keys? I can not see any effect.

Comment: Ok, you mean VS. My problem with VS is that it show only my threads. I can not see a finalizer thread.

Comment: @Horcrux7, you can change threads in `Treads window`. i've just double checked. I see `GC Finalizer Thread` also you can set a breakpoint. But finalizer'll call when gc starts colletion, you can forse it by `GC.Collect()` but it will not happen immediately

Comment: If I set a breakpoint in a destructor then I see the name `GC Finalizer Thread`. But if I stop on another location then I have a thread with no name and no location and the same priority highest.